# How to get object values in a specified manner by with keys and values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

i wanted print the string in a specifed manner but i'm not finding any convenient solution.

**I'm expecting below result:**

```html
 <h1>new_data</h1>

     <h4>print:</h4> <span>inv_val_ads_details_brand,auth_sign</span>

     <h4>report:</h4> <span>value_ads_report,per_day_volume_billing</span>

    <h4>media:</h4> <span>media,auto_generated_media</span>


    <hr>


<h1>old_data</h1>

   <h4>media:</h4> <span>meta_data</span>

   <h4>order:</h4> <span>cg_counter,sub_vertical</span>
```

**here is what i have tried:**

```js
 var data = {
 "new_data": {
  "print": {
   "inv_val_ads_details_brand": true,
   "auth_sign": false
  },
  "report": {
   "value_ads_report": true,
   "per_day_volume_billing": false
  },
  "media": {
   "media": false,
   "auto_generated_media": true
  }
 },
 "old_data": {
  "media": {
   "meta_data": false
  },
  "order": {
   "cg_counter": true,
   "sub_vertical": false
  }
 }
};

var str = '';

   Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
        str += '<h1>'+key+'</h1>';

         console.log('main heading...',key);

         Object.keys(data[key]).map(function(val){
              console.log('values',val);
         });
    });
```

**Question**: snippet 1 output i'm expecting

Please help me thanks in advance  !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you don't return anything, use `forEach` instead of `map`, and doing something like this would give the output you asked for

Stack snippet

```js
var data = {
  "new_data": {
    "print": {
      "inv_val_ads_details_brand": true,
      "auth_sign": false
    },
    "report": {
      "value_ads_report": true,
      "per_day_volume_billing": false
    },
    "media": {
      "media": false,
      "auto_generated_media": true
    }
  },
  "old_data": {
    "media": {
      "meta_data": false
    },
    "order": {
      "cg_counter": true,
      "sub_vertical": false
    }
  }
};

var str = '';

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
  str += '<h1>' + key + '</h1>';

  Object.keys(data[key]).forEach(function(val) {
    str += '<h4>' + val + ':</h4>';

    Object.keys(data[key][val]).forEach(function(val2, idx) {
      if (idx > 0) str += ',';
      str += '<span>' + val2 + '</span>';
    });
  });
});

document.body.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: but you are missing `comma ,` for every items

Comment: @EaB I didn't noticed those in your sample output, now added.